# How should i find objects in Doctrine? DQL or find()

Tags: doctrine, dql

i wonder whats the correct way of finding objects from the database?

i know there's

```
$em->find()
$em->createQuery()
```

i guess `createQuery` will be more like prepared statements thus more secure?

how do i set named parameters in DQL?

```
$em->createQuery('select u from \Entities\Users u WHERE u.name = :name');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the answer [here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#single-scalar-hydration)

```
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT COUNT(a.id) FROM CmsUser u LEFT JOIN u.articles a WHERE u.username = ?1 GROUP BY u.id');
$query->setParameter(1, 'jwage');
$numArticles = $query->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_SINGLE_SCALAR);
```

**`setParameter()`**

I wonder though if `find()` does escape values?

Answer (score 0):

With the 1.X DQL it was

`Doctrine_Query::create()->from("Model m")->addWhere("m.field = ?", $value);`

Something similar should be available in DQL 2.X